# ProgressBar-like bar inside row of TableLayout

Tags: android

I would like to display a ProgressBar-like bar chart inside a row of a TableLayout and have the text of this row displayed on top of the bar chart. The "ProgressBar" would not be moving at runtime but its length shall be caluclated only once at display-time (so it's not really a ProgressBar, but more like a bar chart). The rows of my TableLayout are generated programmically. How would I insert a bar chart into each row? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One solution I implemented for displaying the text on top of the progress bar is to use a FrameLayout like below:

```
<TableRow>
        <!-- First cell with progress and text on top -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        >
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress1"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bg"
                android:indeterminateOnly="false"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:minHeight="22dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="25"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/progress1Text"
                android:text="25"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:gravity="center"
            />
        </FrameLayout>
        <!-- Second cell with some text-->
        <TextView
            android:text="My cell"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />
    </TableRow>
```

You could use this xml and inflate it in Java and set the attributes of the elements as needed then append it to your table.

For the android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bg" I used the following progress_bg.xml (placed in "drawable" floder):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="#80CCCCCC" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="#FFCCCCCC" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```